# Is it better to use a constant or apply_filter?

Tags: filters, constants

I'm using [WPML](https://wpml.org/), which has several ways to access the current language.

**ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE**

```
if( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE === 'en' ){
  // Do stuff
}
```

**apply_filter( 'wpml_current_language', null )'** [docs](https://wpml.org/wpml-hook/wpml_current_language/)

```
$lang = apply_filter( 'wpml_current_language', null );
if( $lang === 'en' ){
  // Do stuff
}
```

---

I can't find any documentation on the ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE.

The `apply_filter` has a documentation page, but in my opinion, the readability drops with this.

Are there any obvious drawbacks using one or the other?

---

### Update

I know that I mentioned WPML, but that was to give the question context. This is WordPress-specific and not 3rd party specific. The dynamic could be anywhere in WordPress, in any plugin and/or theme.

Comment: Sorry, but third party plugin questions are off topic here. Only WPML can tell you the difference between these.

Comment: Thanks for weighing in, @kero . I've updated my question with a comment to your comment. Frankly, I think it's sad that this 'no plugin-related question' is defined. Without plugin-related questions, this Stack Exchange is really narrow. But I guess that's the rules we have to obey. :-/

Comment: This is a question about a plugin's API for getting a specific value, not about WordPress. This choice is not something you'll see in WordPress or other plugins, it's just a choice that this plugin apparently offers. One of them uses a WordPress function, but that's not really relevant. The reason this question is off topic is because it requires knowledge of how the plugin works, not WordPress. For example, without knowing the plugin one can't say how/where the constant is defined, or whether it would reflect the filter, and therefore it's not possible to say whether it's better to use it.

Comment: Not to mention, this is a paid commercial plugin, so the plugin's developers should not be able to get a free ride by relying on this community providing free support.